# Xcode , Parse.com - Push notifications don't show on my phone.

Tags: xcode, swift, push-notification, parse-platform

followed the guide on Parse.com on how to create a certificate and prepare a provisioning account to accept Push Notifications. When i go to Preferences/Accounts : It shows on the bottom, but when i try to choose it from the Build Settings Tab, it doesn't show, and i always get this error : `"no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application"`

My phone is recognised by the Parse app, and it sends notifications successfully, but my phone never receives them. I tried this from scratch several times, using several Xcode & Parse Apps.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        Parse.setApplicationId("MyAppId", clientKey: "MyAppClientKey")

        var notificationType: UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound

        var settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationType, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

        var currentInstallation: PFInstallation = PFInstallation()
        currentInstallation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
        currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {

        println(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you allow push notifications from your app project?

2) Do you have the correct build identifiers set in parse and in your app?

I have another delegate method that I don't see in your post.

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings!) 
    {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

    }
```